# Разбить React приложение на 2 версии viewport

Tags: reactjs

Есть два сайта основной и личный кабинет: один с мобильной версией(адаптив под все устройства), другой фиксированной ширины. Проблема: как совместить два проекта с разными viewport.

Получается, что в первом случае viewport=device-width, а во втором viewport=width=1400. В сборке React есть один файл index.html и один viewport.

Хотелось бы использовать одну сборку React для обоих проектов.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Есть пара идей: 1. Сделать генерацию 2х index файлов и в настройках вебсера добавить условия 2. Попробовать поменять с помощью JS

Comment: Второй вариант не сработает я думаю, а вот первый да, но вот только как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

react-meta-tags отлично справился с задачей

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/740082)